# Python Find Similarities between requests

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, topic-modeling

I am working on a project to analyse the previous requests and if a new request comes, I need to match the earlier request and use the solution provided for the same.

For Example: if these are previous requests "Risk rating for Microsoft Inc", "Report for the month of September", etc and if new request is "Report for the month of September", I need to find the similarities and use the solution provided for one of the matching previous requests.

I am planing to implement in Python. I came across this algorithm for implementation - Topic Modelling and word2vec. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds good. You could implement a cache as well for the exact same request so you don't waste time.

Comment: Will you need to train a model to find semantic similarities? UMLFIT is based on pretrain and you can achieve your goal with few samples.

Comment: @powerPixie Yes I need to train based on the previous requests and if any new requests comes I need to find the nearest match.

Comment: Remember that requests for tutorials are off-topic on Stack Overflow. From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how fast you need the solution to be. If the speed is not an issue, the most accurate will be using some pre-trained contextual representation like [BERT or other "cool Transformers"](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-transformers).

Word embeddings (like word2vec) are certainly a good and fast solution. You only need to tokenize the query, lookup the embeddings in a table a compute an average. Instead of word2vec, you might want to use [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/). It considers also the character *n*-grams while computing the word vector, so it might be more robust to typos. If the requests are longer, the average might noisier, so you might want to remove stop-words.

The good old [Tf-Idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) vectors might also serve well.

Topic modeling (like [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation)) are more suited for longer texts.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that "sentence embedding" was not a thing.

Anyway, here is another approach you might consider.

Here is an example run of [fuzzyhash](https://github.com/amirouche/fuzzyhash) based on [simhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimHash):

```py
In [7]: docs = [ 
   ...: 'Risk rating for Microsoft Inc', 
   ...: "Microsoft ratings", 
   ...: "Report for the month of September", 
   ...: "Report for the month of October" 
   ...: ]   

In [10]: for doc in docs: 
    ...:     print("matching doc", doc, ": ", fuzzyhash.distance(
    ...: fuzzyhash.fuzzyhash("Report for September"), 
    ...: fuzzyhash.fuzzyhash(doc))) 

matching doc Risk rating for Microsoft Inc :  15
matching doc Microsoft ratings :  17
matching doc Report for the month of September :  3
matching doc Report for the month of October :  9
```

It correctly guess that the nearest old requests is "Report for the month of September".